# Ignited Datatables for Codeigniter returns invalid SQL query when used with mysql's date_format function

Tags: codeigniter, datatable

When i use `date_format`, it returns invalid sql query

```
 $this->load->library('Datatables');
 $this->datatables->from('events');
 $this->datatables-select('id,event_name,event_location,DATE_FORMAT(event_start_date,"%b %d %Y, %h:%i %p") as evs,event_type_id,event_status');         echo
 $this->datatables->generate();
```

It returns

```
SELECT `id`, `event_name`, `event_location`, DATE_FORMAT(event_start_date, `"%b` %d %Y, `%h:%i` %p") as evs, `event_type_id`, `event_status` FROM (`events`) ORDER BY `event_name` asc LIMIT 10
```

Comment: link to ignited datatables is http://www.ahmed-samy.com/php-codeigniter-full-featrued-jquery-datatables-part-2/

Comment: try using double qoutes at the main string and single qoutes inside DATE_FORMAT

Comment: still not working, it is adding ```` in between the format being specified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$this->datatables-select('id,event_name,event_location,DATE_FORMAT(event_start_date,"%b %d %Y, %h:%i %p") as evs,event_type_id,event_status',FALSE);
```

Looking ate the github [Library](https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables/blob/master/application/libraries/Datatables.php), he added a second parameter
The second parameter are optional whether to add backticks or not. Set it to `false` so that backticks ` are disabled.

Comment: yeah thanks, its working now, do you know how to use sql joining in this.

Comment: @VipulSharma `$this->datatables->select('*')
         ->from('tabel1')->join('tabel2', 'tabel1.col= tabel2.col');  `

Comment: Thanks, I got it. Please tell me from where I can find all the required documentation regarding Ignited Datatables Library?

Comment: Documentation link -> https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables/wiki/Function-Reference

Answer (score 0):

There is another problem in this,

```
var oTable = $('#dTableEvents').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "/" + PROJECT_NAME + "events/get_all_events",
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "iDisplayStart ": 20,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "oLanguage": {
        "sProcessing": "<img src='/" + PROJECT_NAME + "public/images/ajax-loader.gif'>",
        "sLengthMenu": "Show _MENU_ Entries per Page",
        "sInfo": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ Entries per Page",
        "sInfoEmpty": "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 Entries per Page",
        "sInfoFiltered": "(filterred from _MAX_ total Entries per Page)"
    },
    "aoColumns": [
        {
            "mDataProp": "name",
            "bSearchable": true,
            "bSortable": true,
        },
        {
            "mDataProp": "start_date",
            "bSearchable": true,
            "bSortable": true,
        },
        {
            "mDataProp": "location",
            "bSearchable": true,
            "bSortable": true,
        },
        {
            "mDataProp": "type",
            "bSearchable": true,
            "bSortable": true,
        },
        {
            "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                return '<img alt="" src="/' + PROJECT_NAME + 'public/images/seven-rating.png">';
            },
            "mDataProp": "status",
            "bSearchable": false,
            "bSortable": true,
        }, 
        {
            "fnRender": function (oObj) {
               return '<input type="button" value="Edit" class="edit-btn" onclick="location=\'/'+PROJECT_NAME+'events/edit/' + oObj.aData['id'] + '\'"> <input type="button" value="View" class="edit-btn" onclick="location=\'/'+PROJECT_NAME+'events/view/' + oObj.aData['id'] + '\'">';
            },
            "mDataProp": "__action",
            "bSearchable": false,
            "bSortable": false,
        }

    ],
    "fnInitComplete": function () {
        //oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();

    },
    'fnServerData': function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
        $.ajax({
            'dataType': 'json',
            'type': 'POST',
            'url': sSource,
            'data': aoData,
            'success': fnCallback
        });
    },
    "fnDrawCallback": function()
    {
        $('#dTableEvents tbody td:not(:nth-last-child(-n+1))').addClass('cont-grid bdr-rt-white');
        $('#dTableEvents tbody td:nth-last-child(-n+1)').addClass('cont-grid');
    }
});
```

When i use aoColumns in this, then searching and sorting gets disabled, when i remove aaColumns, then it again starts working.

Comment: I found it, problem with 'as' while taking alias, without as its not working (->select("e.id as id,e.event_name as name,e.event_location as location,DATE_FORMAT(e.event_start_date,'%b %d %Y, %h:%i %p') as start_date,e_t.program_name as type,e.event_status as status",false)) !!